# gocov does not upload the complete test-coverage result into codeclimate

Tags: go, test-coverage, code-climate

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776043/codeclimate-test-coverage-formatter-for-golang) on StackOverflow, I added test coverage into my Gitlab CI/CD YAML file, and I expect the result gets uploaded into codeclimate.

```
- go get github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
- export CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID=My_REPO_ID
- curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > ./cc-test-reporter
- chmod +x ./cc-test-reporter
- ./cc-test-reporter before-build
- gocov test -v ./... -coverprofile=out
- ./cc-test-reporter format-coverage --input-type gocov out
- ./cc-test-reporter upload-coverage
```

The script runs test successfully in all my packages, and the output of CI/CD shows that all tests in different packages ran, but uploaded report into codeclimate only shows there is only one file with test-coverage and that is the last test package, instead of showing all.

[image: code-climate result report page]

Answer (score 0):

I mixed the solution with another answer in the same stackoverflow link and finally create a bash file and ran it from my yaml file like this so the report output contain all package reports, this is my script:

```
go get github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
export CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID=My_ID
curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > ./cc-test-reporter
chmod +x ./cc-test-reporter
./cc-test-reporter before-build

for pkg in $(go list ./... | grep -v vendor); do
    go test -coverprofile=$(echo $pkg | tr / -).cover $pkg
done
echo "mode: set" > c.out
grep -h -v "^mode:" ./*.cover >> c.out
rm -f *.cover

./cc-test-reporter after-build
```